# junit testing for properties file

Tags: java, junit, properties

```
//----my java file---
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(FILE_PATH);
if(is!=null)
{
    prop.load(is);
}
```

It is working fine for main class, but when test it using junit test cases , it is returning null into inputstream,

my folder structure is

```
|_ _src/main/java
|   |_ _ _ MyClass.java
|_ _src/main/resources   
|   |_ _ properties file
|_ _ src/test/java
|   |_ _TestClassFile.java
|_ _ src/test/resources
|   |_ _ test properties file
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the point of having a test properties file? Wouldn't you want to test that your production code simply load "its" properties file correctly?!

Comment: Yes, i tried testing it with the production properties file, but it is returning the null values, Thought it would be the problem with the file path ,So i created test properties file,And then i ran junit in debug mode and the getResourceAsStream is returning null to the 'inputstream' object @GhostCat

Comment: Wrong approach. Make your test setup work with the production properties! Anything else doesn't add value to your test!

Comment: First i tried using the production properties,with the same folder structure , it didn't workout well, so thought of doing it with test properties, Even if i start using the production properties(which i dont specifically ask compiler to pull that file, which it should do that automatically) it is returning null or unable to find the file

Comment: `assertEquals(MyClass.getPrefixes(PROPERTY_NAME),"value");`  this is from my test class
forgot to metion that, getPrefizes is a static method

Comment: Will look into helping you tomorrow.

Comment: i figured it out .. just need to take out the getclassloader and it started working. Thanks for reaching out :)

Comment: You are welcome. You should consider A) adding your comment as answer then; or B) to delete it. But dont leave some "half-baked" things around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking out getClassLoader helped